# How to load JavaAgent and run method from it?

Tags: java, jar, classloader, executable-jar, javaagents

I'm new in JavaAgent concept, so maybe this issue isn't complicated. But I hope some discussion and knowledge arrangement will be helpful (not only for me).

So - what I want to do?
I would like to load external jar library when I start my application. This external library is under development and versioned on ARM (Nexus) and contains functionalities which are essential in my_app.

My attempt:

1. Download wanted version of lib (no problem here - got proper func_version.jar in right place)
2. I add in parent dir of downloaded jar class JavaAgent.java:

   ```
   import java.lang.instrument.*;

   public class JavaAgent {  
       private static Instrumentation inst;  

       public static Instrumentation getInstrumentation() { return inst; }  

       public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {  
           System.out.println(inst.getClass() + ": " + inst);  
           System.out.println("JavaAgent LOADED!");
           JavaAgent.inst = inst;  
       }  
   }
   ```
3. Modify `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in lib (added line: `Premain-Class: JavaAgent`)
4. Try to load JavaAgent by passing it as JVM parameter:

   ```
   java -javaagent:/home/func_1.0.1.jar /home/my_app/MyStartup
   ```

`MyStartup.java` contains main method for my_app.

I know this steps are not enough (can't see any result yet). But is it a right approach? And what else do I need to do to see wanted "JavaAgent LOADED!" on console output? Some work with Java ClassLoader is needed?

Comment: Your java invocation looks wrong (should be something like `java -javaagent:/home/func_1.0.1.jar -cp . MainClass`). What error are you seing?